# python user - retrieve footnotes from html document converted from docx (docx2python not working)

Tags: python, html, regex, xml, docx

I need some help retrieving footnotes from docx documents in python as the docx file contains a large number of footnotes.

Below is the code that I have at the moment which has a problem, since docx2python **cannot** read word documents **more than** certain number of **pages**.

```
from docx2python import docx2python


docx_temp = docx2python(filepath)
footnotes = docx_temp.footnotes
footnotes = footnotes[0][0][0]
footnotes = [i.replace("\t","") for i in footnotes]
```

So I tried other methods below but I'm stuck as I'm unfamiliar with XML, and I'm not sure the codes are working:

```
import re
import mammoth


with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
    html = mammoth.convert_to_html(file).value
    #html = re.sub('\"(.+?)\"', '"<em>\1</em>"', html)
    fnotes = re.findall('id="footnote-<number>" (.*?) ', html)
```

AND

```
import re
import zipfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree
from docx2python import docx2python


docxfile = zipfile.ZipFile(open(filepath,'rb'))
xmlString = docxfile.read('word/footnotes.xml').decode('utf-8')
fn = docxfile.read('word/footnotes.xml')
xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(fn)
```

Could you guys tell me how to correctly write the code to extract footnotes from docx/HTML files. Thanks for your help!

Comment: 0
Down vote
Docx2Python v2.0.0 was uploaded a few hours ago. Give that a try. If not, open an issue on the Docx2Python GitHub page along with a file demonstrating the problem.

https://GitHub.com/ShayHill/Docx2Python

Answer (score 0):

> since docx2python cannot read word documents more than certain number of pages.

Few month ago, I reprogramed docx2python to reproducing a structured(with level) xml format file from a docx file, which works out pretty good on many files. I get no calling for content lossing.

Would you try some other files, or share your file with us, or tell us what you `certain number` is.

As far as I know, footnotes source code in docx2python were written as this `footer = [x for y in footer for x in y]`. If you use `footnotes[0][0][0]` to get footnotes, you may get a wrong one.